# Does there exist a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ s.t. for all $X\subseteq\Bbb N$, if $f^{-1}(X)\neq\emptyset$ then $X=\Bbb N$?

Tags: functions

Does there exist a function $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $
such that for all $ X \subseteq \mathbb{N} $, if $ f^{-1}(X) \neq \emptyset$ then $X = \mathbb{N} $?

I guess not, because that means that image of any subsets of $\mathbb{N} $ must equal $ \emptyset $ or $\mathbb{N} $ however I don't know how to prove it or how to construct such function if it exists. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: No such function exists. Set $X=\{f(1)\}$ to see that any $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ fails the condition.

Comment: @Michael Set $X=\{f(1)\}$ as in Arturo Magidin's comment. Then $f^{-1}(X)\ne\emptyset$ since $1\in f^{-1}(X)$, but $X\ne\mathbb N$ since $f(1)+1\notin X$.